# app crashes when no internet connected

Tags: android, json, connection

i am trying to get data from server, when i disable internet it gives error. my Activitycode is

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hos);

    new ProgressTask(Hospital.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    {
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "INTERNET CONNECTION NOT PRESENT", 5).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Hospital.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

    }

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.row_listitem, new String[] { name, contact },
                new int[] { R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor });


        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) lv
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                String name = map.get("name");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Hospital.this,
                        DataViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemName", name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        baseAdapter jParser = new baseAdapter();

        // get JSON data from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String vtype = c.getString(name);

                String vcolor = c.getString(contact);
                String vfuel = c.getString(Category);
                // String vtread = c.getString(TREAD);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                map.put(name, vtype);
                map.put(contact, vcolor);
                map.put(Category, vfuel);
                // map.put(TREAD, vtread);
                jsonlist.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

baseAdapter:

```
public class baseAdapter {

static InputStream iStream = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public baseAdapter() {
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jarray;

}
```

logcat:

```
08-16 12:36:00.271: E/JSON Parser(17005): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-16 12:36:00.271: W/dalvikvm(17005): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7f228)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at com.example.careandcure.Hospital$ProgressTask.doInBackground(Hospital.java:124)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at com.example.careandcure.Hospital$ProgressTask.doInBackground(Hospital.java:1)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-16 12:36:00.281: E/AndroidRuntime(17005):
```

my question is when i connect the internet it works fine but when i disconnect it crashes the app and also shows toast not internet connection

Comment: what is in line 124 @ `Hospital.java` ?

Comment: You forgot to call `close()` on your input streams and http connections.

Comment: // get JSON data from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

Comment: can you tell me where you check internet connection? where do those lines of codes be supposed to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have a internet connection following line return null to you:

```
 jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

so `json` is null in your code and you can't run following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
```

for solving this issue you can check `json` that is not null

```
if (json != null)
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written assuming the attempt to get the json will work and be valid.  If you have no internet connection it will timeout instead.  In that case json will be null.  You need to check for that case and handle it.